# How to read only lines that fulfil a condition from a csv into R?

Tags: r, large-data, read.csv

I am trying to read a large csv file into R. I only want to read and work with some of the rows that fulfil a particular condition (e.g. `Variable2 >= 3`). This is a much smaller dataset.

I want to read these lines directly into a dataframe, rather than load the whole dataset into a dataframe and then select according to the condition, since the whole dataset does not easily fit into memory.

Comment: How 'large' is your file? Can't you start reading 1000 lines and subset them to your condition at every loop?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I was reading 1 million lines at a time. Each iteration was taking about 15 seconds, including adding the resulting "filtered" dataset to an existing dataframe. But given the size of the dataset I am dealing with, this solution would have taken more than 1 hour. As I wrote below, the solution I actually used (sqldf) took slightly less than one hour. Dirk's suggestion of awk for my problem would have taken about 2 hours. I will look into Python to accelereate some of these tasks. If someone has good pointers, let me know. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know it worked better with sqldf. Definitely something to retain.

Comment: This is a very common question, but the 'best' answer for each use-case depends on what sort of condition, is it simple number/string-matching on one or more fields (use grep/awk), or does it require evaluating multiple fields (e.g. `V2*V3 < mean(V4) & !is.na(V5)`)? If a simple grep/awk gets 90+% of the coarse size reduction done, it's one good way to go.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use the `read.csv.sql` function in the `sqldf` package and filter using SQL select. From the help page of `read.csv.sql`:

```
library(sqldf)
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
iris2 <- read.csv.sql("iris.csv", 
    sql = "select * from file where `Sepal.Length` > 5", eol = "\n")
```

Comment: How does this solve the "file too big for current memory" problem?

Comment: The sqlite database used under the hood is by default a temporary file, hence no memory problem, I suppose.

Comment: This was the fastest way to solve my problem in R. It took about 1 hour. Thanks!

Comment: At least in my version of R (3.4.2) running on Linux, the above example did not work without the addition of apostrophe's around `Sepal.Length`, i.e. I needed to use `\`Sepal.Length\``.

Answer (score 26):

By far the easiest (in my book) is to use pre-processing.

```
R> DF <- data.frame(n=1:26, l=LETTERS)
R> write.csv(DF, file="/tmp/data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
R> read.csv(pipe("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\",\"} {if ($1 > 20) print $0}' /tmp/data.csv"),
+           header=FALSE)
  V1 V2
1 21  U
2 22  V
3 23  W
4 24  X
5 25  Y
6 26  Z
R>
```

Here we use `awk`. We tell `awk` to use a comma as a field separator, and then use the conditon 'if first field greater than 20' to decide if we print (the whole line via `$0`).

The output from that command can be read by R via `pipe()`.

This is going to be faster and more memory-efficient than reading everythinb into R.

Comment: And will this work with a million(s) lines DF as well?

Comment: Yes, sure. You only read the percentage satisfying the condition.  `awk` processes this one line at a time.

Comment: This is interesting but I can't get it working from RStudio with your simple example. Something with the awk filter but not sure (no lines available in input)...

Comment: You need `awk` in your path, and I assumed a Unix layout here with `/tmp`.  You need to adjust that as needed.

Comment: Sure, that works too. In fact, on my Linux system `awk` is in fact `gawk`.

Comment: Awesome @DirkEddelbuettel could you give me the name of your book. And second I have a similar problem but with a .txt file. It has in the first 300 rows with sql errors and after of these is the data separated by tab but I tried to read it and I only got a dataframe of one column. Could you suggest me any way to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: I can run a modified string from command prompt: `"awk "BEGIN {FS=\",\"} {if ($1 > 20) print $0}" /tmp/data.csv"` works for me changing quotes from `'` to `"` but I can't find a way to run it from R nor with `pipe`or `system`.

Comment: I cut and pasted the actual command from a working session.  I use outer "" for the actual string R passes to as an argument to `pipe()`.  Inside the string, use single quotes for the argument to awk.  Inside the single quote, escape quotes for the FS argument.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel This is very helpful! Where can I find more info about `awk`?

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, Thanks so much for this answer. I was not familiar with awk but this works. I accepted the answer below because it ended up being a bit faster for my particular problem (no idea why). But I wanted to thank for always teaching us newbies something useful. I bought your rcpp book last week. ;)

Comment: Another external tool `csvtk` from https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk may also be tried.

Answer (score 20):

I was looking into `readr::read_csv_chunked` when I saw this question and thought I would do some benchmarking. For this example, `read_csv_chunked` does well and increasing the chunk size was beneficial. `sqldf` was only marginally faster than `awk`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sqldf)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

# Generate an example dataset with two numeric columns and 5 million rows
tibble(
  norm = rnorm(5e6, mean = 5000, sd = 1000),
  unif = runif(5e6, min = 0, max = 10000)
) %>%
  write_csv('medium.csv')

microbenchmark(
  readr  = read_csv_chunked('medium.csv', callback = DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, pos) subset(x, unif > 9000)), col_types = 'dd', progress = F),
  readr2 = read_csv_chunked('medium.csv', callback = DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, pos) subset(x, unif > 9000)), col_types = 'dd', progress = F, chunk_size = 1000000),
  sqldf  = read.csv.sql('medium.csv', sql = 'select * from file where unif > 9000', eol = '\n'),
  awk    = read.csv(pipe("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\",\"} {if ($2 > 9000) print $0}' medium.csv")),
  awk2   = read_csv(pipe("awk 'BEGIN {FS=\",\"} {if ($2 > 9000) print $0}' medium.csv"), col_types = 'dd', progress = F),
  fread  = fread(cmd = "awk 'BEGIN {FS=\",\"} {if ($2 > 9000) print $0}' medium.csv"),
  check  = function(values) all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) all.equal(values[[1]], x))),
  times  = 10L
)

# Updated 2020-05-29

# Unit: seconds
#   expr   min    lq  mean  median    uq   max neval
#  readr   2.6   2.7   3.1     3.1   3.5   4.0    10
# readr2   2.3   2.3   2.4     2.4   2.6   2.7    10
#  sqldf  14.1  14.1  14.7    14.3  15.2  16.0    10
#    awk  18.2  18.3  18.7    18.5  19.3  19.6    10
#   awk2  18.1  18.2  18.6    18.4  19.1  19.4    10
#  fread  17.9  18.0  18.2    18.1  18.2  18.8    10

# R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
# macOS Mojave 10.14.6        

# data.table 1.12.8
# readr      1.3.1 
# sqldf      0.4-11
```

Comment: Do you mind adding `data.table::fread(cmd="awk ...")` for benchmarking?

Comment: @zx8754 of course! Though, for this example `awk` does the heavy lifting. Is there a chunked reading capability in `data.table`?

Comment: I think another external tool called `csvtk` from https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/ may also be used with `fread` for testing.

Answer (score 9):

You can read the file in chunks, process each chunk, and then stitch only the subsets together.

Here is a minimal example assuming the file has 1001 (incl. the header) lines and only 100 will fit into memory. The data has 3 columns, and we expect at most 150 rows to meet the condition (this is needed to pre-allocate the space for the final data:

```
# initialize empty data.frame (150 x 3)
max.rows <- 150
final.df <- data.frame(Variable1=rep(NA, max.rows=150), 
                       Variable2=NA,  
                       Variable3=NA)

# read the first chunk outside the loop
temp <- read.csv('big_file.csv', nrows=100, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
temp <- temp[temp$Variable2 >= 3, ]  ## subset to useful columns
final.df[1:nrow(temp), ] <- temp     ## add to the data
last.row = nrow(temp)                ## keep track of row index, incl. header

for (i in 1:9){    ## nine chunks remaining to be read
  temp <- read.csv('big_file.csv', skip=i*100+1, nrow=100, header=FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  temp <- temp[temp$Variable2 >= 3, ]
  final.df[(last.row+1):(last.row+nrow(temp)), ] <- temp
  last.row <- last.row + nrow(temp)    ## increment the current count
}

final.df <- final.df[1:last.row, ]   ## only keep filled rows
rm(temp)    ## remove last chunk to free memory
```

**Edit:** Added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option on @lucacerone's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: out of curiousity: say that while importing I realize that preallocating 150 rows wasn't enough, is there an efficient way to extend the rows of the final data.frame (say by other 150 rows)?

Comment: just one small not: I would use the option stringsAsFactors = FALSE when you import the data: it might be that for categorical variables you don't read all the categories with the first chunks, and R doesn't make you add data for which you don't have categories...

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I will edit the solution. To my knowledge there is no efficient way to add lines without R rewriting the whole thing, but if you do extend it (say by another 50) it will still only be one rewrite.

Comment: I think stringsAsFactors = FALSE should be added to final.df too.

I am surprised though that there is not base function to let you do something similar...

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. It will be passed as a `character` value and will not conflict with the other chunks, also `character`.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file in read mode using the function `file` (e.g. `file("mydata.csv", open = "r")`).

You can read the file one line at a time using the function `readLines` with option `n = 1`, `l = readLines(fc, n = 1)`.

Then you have to parse your string using function such as `strsplit`, regular expressions, or you can try the package `stringr` (available from CRAN).

If the line met the conditions to import the data, you import it.

To summarize I would do something like this:

```
df = data.frame(var1=character(), var2=int(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fc = file("myfile.csv", open = "r")

i = 0
while(length( (l <- readLines(fc, n = 1) ) > 0 )){ # note the parenthesis surrounding l <- readLines..

   ##parse l here: and check whether you need to import the data.

   if (need_to_add_data){
     i=i+1
     df[i,] = #list of data to import
  }

}
```

Comment: This will work, but it'll be relatively slow.  It's almost always fastest to edit the source file before reading into `R`, e.g. using a simple text editor or tools like `sed` and `awk`

Comment: So he did, but sometimes ... "Let It Bleed," Track 9 .

Comment: You could make this a lot faster by reading in (say) 10,000 lines at a time.

Comment: @hadley beat me to it. You can read it by chunks. You should also pre-allocate `df` or it will take very long, basically rewriting the entire data on each iteration (millions of times). I've added a proof-of-concept solution.