# How to only read part of a large CSV file in R?

Tags: r, large-files, read.table

I am dealing with large csv files but actually I only need a small part of it. What I do now is something like this:

```
df <- read.table('large.csv')
df <- df[df$ID == 100, ]
```

This is very inefficient in terms of time and memory. Is there a way to only read in the lines with ID ==100 in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: This very similar question may be helpful to you:  [How do i read only lines that fulfil a condition from a csv into R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197243/how-do-i-read-only-lines-that-fulfil-a-condition-from-a-csv-into-r)