# Read in a table that meets specific requirements in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am reading in data from a .txt file that contains over thousands of records

```
table1 <- read.table("teamwork.txt", sep ="|", fill = TRUE)
```

Looks like:

```
f_name  l_name hours_worked  code

Jim      Baker    8.5        T
Richard  Copton  4.5         M
Tina     Bar     10          S
```

However I only want to read in data that has a 'S' or 'M' code:

I tried to concat the columns:

```
newdata <- subset(table1, code = 'S' |'M')
```

However I get this issue:

> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. The error comes from using `=` instead of `==`. Try `subset(table1, code == 'S' | code == 'M')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are thousands or tens of thousands of records (maybe not for millions), you should just be able to filter after you read in all the data:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> df %>% filter(code=="S"|code=="M")
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  f_name  l_name hours_worked code 
  <fct>   <fct>         <dbl> <fct>
1 Richard Copton         4.50 M    
2 Tina    Bar           10.0  S
```

If you really want to just pull in the rows that meet your condition, try `sqldf` package as in example here: [How do i read only lines that fulfil a condition from a csv into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197243/how-do-i-read-only-lines-that-fulfil-a-condition-from-a-csv-into-r)

Comment: It is giving me `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'code' not found.` error any idea on it please?

Comment: I loaded in your data that you included in the question as a data frame called `df` with four variables: `f_name`, `l_name`, `hours_worked`, and `code`. If your data frame name is different, just replace `df` in the above code; similarly, if your variable name is different than `code`, you will have to use your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
cols_g <- table1[which(table1$code == "S" | table1$code == "M",]
```

OR

```
cols_g <- subset(table1, code=="S" | code=="M")
```

OR

```
library(dplyr)
cols_g <- table1 %>% filter(code=="S" | code=="M")
```

If you want to add column `cols_g` on `table1`, you can use `table1$cols_g` assigned anything from these 3 methods instead of `cols_g`.